# How to allow users to add custom domains on our web app like wix, appflow and heroku?

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain, heroku, react-js

We are building a web app in ReactJS which allows users to create websites for their real estate listings. A user has to select a subdomain for themselves and all of their listing website have a separate link, something in this format: `theirsubdomain.ourappdomain.example/listing/[listingid]`.

As a next feature, we want our users to be able to add a custom domain for each of their listing websites, say `domainA.example` and whenever someone opens `domainA.example`, it takes them to the links associated with the listing website on our web app so it looks like someone has opened `domainA.example` and the browser in the URL says `domainA.example` but it actually displays content from the link `theirsubdomain.ourappdomain.example/listing/[listingid]`.

So far we have tried domain URL frame redirection from user's hosting panel. The issue is that not every hosting provider allows doing URL frame redirection and if it is not URL frame redirection, the redirection works but the URL in the browser also changes.

Our app is deployed on heroku servers.

Comment: Are your URLs defined client side in JavaScript using the router built into React?

Comment: Yes. They are defined on client application with react router. We get listing ID from the URL, fetch listing's information and display on the page.